# javadoc generate empty folder in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

When I try to generate javadoc using `project->generate javadoc` it creates only empty folder.
My `javadoc generation` windows looks like this
[image]
[image]
[image]

And when I click finish - it creates empty folder. 
What's the problem?